# Angular observable - how to return true or false from subscription to observable

Tags: javascript, angular, observable, ngx-bootstrap-modal

I have a function `canDeactivate` that should either return `true` or `false`. This can be determined by the result of calling an `openConfirmDialog()` function, which opens an ngx-bootstrap modal 'confirm' dialog and waits for the user response (which can either result in `true` or `false`). Here is the code:

```
  canDeactivate(component: ComponentCanDeactivate): boolean | Observable<boolean> {
    // if there are no pending changes, just allow deactivation; else confirm first
    return component.canDeactivate() ?
      true :
      this.openConfirmDialog();
  }

  openConfirmDialog() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ConfirmationComponent);
    return this.modalRef.content.onClose.subscribe(result => {
        console.log('results', result);
    })
  }
```

The `result` from subscribing to `this.modalRef.content.onClose` is working. I can successfully log `true` or `false`. When the result becomes either `true` or `false` though, how do I *return* `true` or `false` as the value of `canDeactivate`? Or am I missing the point, and should I be doing things a different way?

My `ConfirmationComponent` looks like this, which defines `onClose` as an `Observable<boolean>` (specifically a `Subject<boolean>`), so I can successfully return a boolean observable, but how do I get my `canDeactivate` to return `true` or `false` whenever `openConfirmDialog` receives a value of `true` or `false`?

```
@Component({
    templateUrl: './confirmation.component.html'
})
export class ConfirmationComponent {

    public onClose: Subject<boolean>;

    constructor(private _bsModalRef: BsModalRef) {

    }

    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.onClose = new Subject();
    }

    public onConfirm(): void {
        this.onClose.next(true);
        this._bsModalRef.hide();
    }

    public onCancel(): void {
        this.onClose.next(false);
        this._bsModalRef.hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: You  could map the observable returned by `onClose` to a  boolean observable. The interface from canDeactivate expects a return of type boolean, observable<boolean> or promise<boolean>

Comment: Thanks David I think I'm already doing what you suggest - I've posted some more code to show what's happening a little deeper down. Hopefully I've now clarified what I'm asking?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to @David I changed my subscription to `onClose` to a `map` rather than a `subscribe` and this works:

```
  openConfirmDialog() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ConfirmationComponent);
    // line below - change from 'subscribe' to 'map'
    return this.modalRef.content.onClose.map(result => {
        return result;
    })
  }
```

However, as @Ingo Burk has pointed out, I can simply use:

```
  openConfirmDialog() {
    this.modalRef = this.modalService.show(ConfirmationComponent);
    return this.modalRef.content.onClose;
  }
```

Comment: The `map` part isn't doing anything now. You can just drop that operator.